# How do Left join in Ebean?

Tags: java, left-join, ebean

Table1: AuthorizedDomainReview

- uid int;
- ...

Table2: Advertiser

- advertiserid int;
- reviewStatus enum('pending','Approved','Rejected');

so: I'm trying to come up with the Ebean equivalent of this sql:

select a.* from AuthorizedDomainReview a left join Advertiser b on a.uid = b.advertiserId where b.reviewStatus ='Approved';

Thanks

Comment: we are also currently looking for a solution for this. in the past we "solved" this by using the ebean RawSql class.